# Unity3D Getting OVRCameraRig's CenterEyeAnchor movespeed

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

How to get  movespeed of  Unity3D Getting OVRCameraRig's CenterEyeAnchor

get the method to get the speed of CenterEyeAnchor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.